# convergence of $(\frac{1}{2\cdot 4})^p+(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4\cdot6})^p+(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8})^p+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Which test to apply to test the convergence of the following infinite series

$$\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot 4}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4\cdot6}\right)^p+\left(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8}\right)^p+\cdots$$

Attempt: I applied the ratio test that is inconclusive, then I went on to apply the Rabbes test, but I cannot evaluate the limit in this case.

Comment: Do you know [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: @Feng Yes ! But how to use that here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

The series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, where
$$a_n=\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n)\cdot(2n+2)}\right)^p=\left(\frac1{2n+1}\frac{(2n+2)!}{((2n+2)!!)^2}\right)^p=\left(\frac1{2^{2n+2}(2n+1)}\frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}\right)^p\geq0.$$
By [Stiriling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we have
$$(2n+2)!\sim \sqrt{4\pi(n+1)}\left(\frac{2n+2}e\right)^{2n+2},\qquad n\to\infty,$$
$$((n+1)!)^2\sim 2\pi(n+1)\left(\frac{n+1}e\right)^{2n+2},\qquad n\to\infty.$$
Therefore,
$$a_n\sim \left(\frac1{(2n+1)\sqrt{\pi(n+1)}}\right)^p,\qquad n\to\infty,$$
i.e.,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^{-3p/2}}=c\in(0,\infty).$$
Now we just need to apply the limit comparison test.